# Django ListView, split list into categories in template, by modifying a "current_category" variable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I don't really know how to phrase my question, but what I'm trying to do is add a title between items to split them into obvious categories on my template. I would like to do this:

```
{# set variable "current_category" to an empty value first #}

{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.category != current_category %}
        {{ current_category = item.category }} {# <-- How to do that? #}
        <h1>{{ item.category }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then end up with:

```
<h1>Cat 1</h1>
<p>item</p>
<p>item</p>
...
<h1>Cat 2</h1>
<p>item</p>
..
```

I saw on similar answers that there are things called [custom filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/) and [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) but it seems really complicated for something very simple. Is this really the only way to do that?

**NOTE: I already ordered the items by category of course**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for Django's [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag, which does exactly what you're asking for.

```
{% regroup items by category as grouped_items %}

{% for category, item_list in grouped_items %}
  <h1>{{ category }}</h1>
  {% for item in item_list %}
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow amazing! Good work Django, I thought it was weird that the Django staff hadn't thought about that haha. Thanks a lot, friend!